# Why in worst case insert and delete take linear time for hash table?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, hash

In the book grokking algorithms, the author said that

> In the worst case, a hash table takes O(n)—linear time—for everything, which is really slow.

In worst case, I understand that hash function will map all the keys in the same slots, the hash table start a linked list at that slot to store all the items. So for search it will take linear time because you have to scan all the items one by one.

What I don't understand is that for insert and delete, that hash table take linear time to perform. In worst case, all the items are stored in the same slot which points to a linked list. And for linked list, delete and insert take constant time. Why hash table take linear time?

For insert, can hash table just append the item at the end of linked list? It will take constant time.

Comment: Delete-by-value takes linear time in a linked-list. Delete-by-node-pointer (or reference) takes constant time, but you generally don't have the linked-list node pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And for linked list, delete and insert take constant time.

They don't. They take linear time, because you have to find the item to delete (or the place to insert) first.

Comment: For insert, can hash table just append the item at the end of linked list? It will take constant time.

Comment: But you need to search to make sure that there is no duplicate item.

Comment: @invisal: Actually, that's a good point the OP made. You *can* blindly append new items at the end, because linear search guarantees that you always return the first instance. This means, however, that you need to make sure during deletion that *all* instances are deleted, i.e. you always need to traverse the entire list. It also means that you cannot distinguish between "item added" and "item was already there" in the API. For example, you cannot implement Java's `Map.put` correctly this way.

Comment: But hash table insertion operation does not allow duplicate or else it does not make sense. `a.put("key1", 10);` and `a.put("key1", 20);` so what is the value of `a["key1"]`

Comment: @X.Wang, one more thing, we can make the worst time of  hash table to `log(n)` if you use balanced binary search tree instead of the linked list.

Comment: @invisal: It's `10`, as it should be, because it was inserted first, and thus will always be found first during a linear search. The only two differences to the normal approach are: 1) during deletion, you always need to iterate until the very end of the list, you cannot stop once you found the key. And 2) you cannot tell during insertion whether the key was already there or not. This means that you cannot correctly implement Java's `Map.put`, but it is perfectly legal for Ruby's `Hash#[]=`, for example.

Comment: This would also means two more things : the table can take more space than O(n) and deletion can also take more time than O(n) in the worst case with n being the number of keys in the map. They would both take O(m) with m the number of inserts.

Answer (score 3):

Delete will not be constant: you will have to visit the whole worst case linked-list to find the object you want to delete. So this would also be a O(n) complexity.

You will have the same problem to insert: you don't want any duplicates, therefore, to be sure not to create some of them ,you will have to check the whole linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Because in order to insert and delete, you need to make search and search takes O(n) in worst case. Therefore, it should also takes at least O(n) in worst case as well.